# python-mapscript on OSX Yosemite

Tags: python, gdal, osx, mapscript

I am keen to try out the mapserver export plugin from QGIS 2.6

This needs python-mapscript which comes from the mapserver package. This can be downloaded from http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/mapserver BUT there is a dependency on GDAL Framework 1.9 and I cannot find a package to install this (the kyngchaos packages are at version 1.11)

Is there any other way apart from a complete build from source to achieve this?

Comment: You can find all the archives in [Kyng Chaos: Unix Port Download Archive](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive)

Comment: Thanks, downloaded GDAL 1.9.0 framework, this will not run as it wants SQLIte3 framework, yet this is installed. I can see it in /Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.Framework

Comment: This a problem of version compatibility. I assume you have installed the last version of all the frameworks and GDAL 1.9 is not the last.

Comment: I already had GDAL 1.11 installed, then (probably mistakenly) installed GDAL 1.9 from your link.